# Chart.js Radar Labels Coordinates

Tags: javascript, charts, coordinates, chart.js

is there any way to get the coordinates for the labels in the radar chart?
I'm trying to put images instead of text in the labels area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate it using the scale property. Here is something that draws a blue circle at those points after the animation completes.

```
onAnimationComplete: function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.scale.valuesCount; i++) {
        // get the poitn position
        var pointLabelPosition = this.scale.getPointPosition(i, this.scale.calculateCenterOffset(this.scale.max) + 5);

        // draw a circle at that point
        this.chart.ctx.beginPath();
        this.chart.ctx.arc(pointLabelPosition.x, pointLabelPosition.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        this.chart.ctx.fillStyle = '#77e';
        this.chart.ctx.fill();
        this.chart.ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/1jgmbyb7/